# How to use AJAX to update ACF field within a loop

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am running a loop which displays posts of a custom type. Each post has a `<button class=favorite-toggle>add to favorites</button>`. When a user clicks the button, I would like that post object to be added to a repeater field specific to that user.

How can I accomplish this using AJAX? My basic understanding is that I will need to pass the post_ID and user_ID variables to JS, and then via the AJAX function, pass the variables to a new PHP file which will contain my function, but I am lost in making this happen. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which JS/PHP frameworks you have available, but a vanilla solution for the HTML + JS will be something like this:

```js
var btnAddToFavorites = document.getElementById('js-add-to-favorites');
btnAddToFavorites.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let _data = {
    post_ID: "1234"
  }

  fetch("addToFavourite.php", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(_data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log("success")
      console.log(json)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

```html
<button class="favorite-toggle" id="js-add-to-favorites">Add to Favorites</button>
```

and PHP `addToFavourite.php`

```
<?php
$body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$object = json_decode($body, true);
print_r($object);
?>
```

There are a few ways to get the Post ID into your JS function. If you don't have any data/viewmodel in your JS already, then assuming you have PHP generating the page, you could add it to the button

```
<button class="favorite-toggle" id="js-add-to-favorites" data-postid="1234">Add to Favorites</button>
```

and load it in JS with

```
e.getAttribute("data-postid")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I'm still having a little trouble getting this working, but I'm sure it's my fault somehow. First, I am getting an error in my console: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0".

Also, in the addToFavorite.php file, how do I then access the data that was passed through and use it to do an update_field() function for an ACF field?

Comment: @ArtVandelay001 youll want the json to start with a `{` or a `[` , try logging/printing the value just before it goes through a JSON function so you can try to figure out how to get there. For accessing the data in PHP i believe its `$object['post_ID']` for an array, and `$object->post_ID` for an object